# my source code are deleted after axecuting mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I used this tutorial to create a maven web project that I can use in eclipse

http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-web-application-project-with-maven/

The last step is executing the commande : mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0
This step helps me add the required librairies included in my pom file.
The problem is that any source folder that I add in my ressources folder created by default is deleted after executing that commande.
Is there any way to add other sources folders without being deleted after executing that command.

Thank you :)

Comment: You can try to do a `mvn eclipse:eclipse` then import your project as a maven project in eclipse.

Comment: But if I don't add -Dwtpversion=2.0 it's not going to be detected as a web project in eclipse. My goal is to have a web project created by maven detected as a web project in eclipse.

Comment: But it's already imported, and when i do a refresh in eclipse I find that the source folder that I created in eclipse is gone, I don't know but it seems that it was deleted by maven when I used that command.

Comment: Did you re-import using import->maven project after issuing the command mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0?

Comment: I solved the problem,
It seems that maven respect a naming convention to name folders,
This website explaine the Standard Directory Layout used in maven.

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, It seems that maven respect a naming convention to name folders, This website explaine the Standard Directory Layout used in maven.

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html